Want to write a Date in Column Dates at A2 celladdress that recognise as Date Format using xlsx or other Library in Webdriver io Project
I have a requirement in my project of webdriver io. I want to read an xlsx file from my project explorer path. That file has some column include Date.
IN the Date column value. I want to write the Date in Date format that identifies as Date instead of General.
I am using xlsx library to read the file first. and then I am idetifying the Cell Address Based Based on column and row index. I have to write the Date format value in cellAddress A2.
The Date I am storing in a const variable from the application using getValue() method.
so it store the date in a string format
const date = $('xpath').getValue();  //  2024-04-23    //yyyy-mm-dd
const[year,month,date] = date.split("-");
I want to write the date in my provided cell address in mm/dd/yyyy format
const newFormat = ${month}/{date}/{year};
worksheet[cellAddress]:{t:'s',v:newFormat,d:'mm/dd/yyyy'};
Even I am changing the t to d or n using serialNumber. In that case also, it's not working. I can write the Date but in General Format.
which is 04/25/2024 that identifies as general when we right click on cell and check the format cell. I want this to be Date in the given format.
I have tried all the possible way to do that but nothing works. Can someone help me to achive to so I can write the Data for Date that appears Date in Date format
Like: 04/25/2024 and it recognise as Date not as General Text.
Let me know solution with any other library required to format in Date. My current system regional timezone format is mm/dd/yyyy only.
I have already explained above what I have tried.
